# #with(object) &block trick

Tags: ruby, idioms

There is a common idiom of using substitutions like:

```
def with clazz, &block
  yield clazz
  clazz
end

with Hash.new |hash|
  hash.merge!{:a => 1}
end
```

Is there a way to go further and define #with to have a possibility of doing:

```
with Hash.new |hash|
  merge!{:a => 1} 
end
```

or even:

```
with Hash.new do
  merge!{:a => 1}
end
```

?

---

**UPDATE**

Later accidentally I found exactly what I was looking for (solution similar to the accepted one):
http://blade.nagaokaut.ac.jp/cgi-bin/scat.rb/ruby/ruby-core/19153

**UPDATE 2**

It was added to sugar-high/dsl in https://github.com/kristianmandrup/sugar-high

**UPDATE 3**

[docille project on Github](https://github.com/ms-ati/docile) exploits this idea very nicely.

Comment: What for? You can choose your block variable to be as short as you like. What would you save? And by the way, you missed `do`.

Comment: Focus on question, please! Is it finally possible?

Comment: "There is a common idiom of using substitutions like" - `[citation needed]`.

Comment: Last thing that you want to achieve is possible (by instance_eval), but it yields some problems: this block won't be treated as closure anymore, and it will be called with different binding. Such code is very easy to start being unreadable.

Comment: "...this block won't be treated as closure anymore, and it will be called with different binding". Could you please explain it in more detailed way? Or give and example... I know instance_eval gives restrictions but I think those ones who will use such #with method understand them. Maybe I am overlooking something?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you are referring to the way in which Rails does routing then I think you need to do something like this

```
def with(instance, &block)
  instance.instance_eval(&block)
  instance
end

with(Hash.new) do
  merge!({:a => 1})
  merge!({:b => 1})
end
```

This is how I can see it being done in the Rails source anyway start by looking at the draw method in [action_pack/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb)

Answer (score 3):

Isn't your pseudo-Ruby:

```
with Hash.new do |hash|
  merge!{:a => 1} 
end
```

The same thing as using 1.9's [`tap`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Object.html#M001035)? For example:

```
>> x = Hash[:a, :b].tap { |h| h.merge!({:c => :d}) }
=> {:a=>:b, :c=>:d}
```

You still have to name the block argument of course.

Comment: You're right. They're very similar. But I want to avoid calls on variable passed to block, but directly! like Hash[:a, :b].some_cool_method { merge!({:c => :d}) }

Answer (score 1):

You can use the ruby builtin `tap`:

```
Hash.new.tap do |hash|
  hash.merge! a: 1
end
```

This can even be "abused" for multiple objects:

```
[one_long_name, another_long_name].tap do |(a,b)|
  a.prop = b.prop
end
```

Of course both don't give you exactly what `with` would do according to your example: The block won't be evaluated within the instance of the object. But I prefer a lot to use `tap` with multiple objects, plus `tap` return `self`, so it can be chained:

```
[one_long_name, another_long_name].tap {|(a,b)| a.prop = b.prop }.inspect
```